# application crash at strncpy in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I get an access violation at strncpy in the below code.

```
if(WaitForSingleObject(RdStatShared.hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    if(RdStatShared.Resp.itemLength != NULL)
    {                   
        strncpy((char*)TData[53], (char*)RdStatShared.Resp.itemLength, (size_t)0x01);
    }
    ReleaseMutex(RdStatShared.hMutex);
}
```

RdStatShared is a shared object used across project. Since it is updated randomly, I wanted to lock the object before reading it.
TData is BYTE type of length 1024 and itemLength is a UCHAR.

While debugging code, in the assembly code i see that access violation accurred when copying source string into a temporary buffer. 
Can any one tell why access violation occurred at strncpy?

Thanks for any useful information.

Lakshmi.

Comment: itemLength really is a UCHAR? not UCHAR*? If so I do believe that is the issue...

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `strncpy` is the location to copy to, and you seem to be passing `RdStatShared.Resp.itemLength`, which sounds suspiciously like the size of something, and *not* like a pointer to a character buffer. If you want to interpret it as such, then you probably need to pass a pointer to it, not the thing itself; i.e.,  `(char*) &(RdStatShared.Resp.itemLength)` .

Comment: @Hans: yeah, I didn't read too closely. You're absolutely right.